# Text verification captcha non visible error while registering facebook via Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, captcha

Trying to register new Facebook account using TOR browser.
Security text check (captcha) are not displayed.
Have tried using Facebook.com and m.Facebook.com and also the onion address. Same blank or null image. Audio captcha do not work too.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using Tor browser bundle? It sounds like you have disabled JavaScript if you are. Click on the Tor Button (The green onion icon) on your Tor browser and select Privacy and Security Settings slide the "Security Level" slider to Medium-Low or Low to enable JavaScript. Also, you may wan to try a public wifi Or VPN without using Tor just for the registration.

Comment: Gooe evening. javascript is enabled and security level is set as low. Just try to reset to default values and same result. I've already tested it using tails 2.4 and same result.

Comment: Yes bundle if it means tor for windows.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: "In my case a workaround is to click the Try another text button which then seems to produce a usable captcha." No longer a viable workaround. I used to use that, too. Facebook have the resources to get this right. I assume it's hostility to privacy?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on TailsOS. Have tried the Clearnet address, the .onion address, with/without javascript clicking "Try Another Text" multiple times, all I get is the broken image placeholder icon. I am beyond annoyed and very angry (incompetence is one of my biggest hot buttons). Did Facebook not bother test their product throughly to ensure it works under all conditions? I notice that the other posts here are many months old. Has anyone made Facebook aware of this problem? Do they give a crap to fix it? Many anti-privacy dilldo's at Facebook need to be $hitcanned over this and I s

Comment: I can see the Captcha in Tor Browser if I disable the NoScript Addon. I recommend to restart it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this, I think it's actually a bug in facebook's captcha mechanism.

From what I can see, it's requesting `/tfbimage.php?captcha_challenge_code=foo&captcha_challenge_auth=bar` and that request is itself receiving a redirect to `/login.php?next=<the previous URL for the captcha image>` which obviously doesn't return a captcha image.

Essentially it's asking you to login to retrieve the captcha (which you're probably getting...because you're not logged in. derp.)

Google's recaptcha did a similar thing previously on cloudflare, where requests for the captcha image got 403'd *(Forbidden)* so you couldn't fetch the mechanism to show you weren't a bot...because it thought you were a bot.

cc @alec-muffett

In my case a workaround is to click the `Try another text` button which then seems to produce a usable captcha.

There's not much else to be done from your side except try the workaround, it looks like an issue (or an intentional tactic? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) on facebook's side

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to modify the URL so that it begins with https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ - that's Facebook's official .onion address, and the CAPTCHA works there.

Comment: I get the same problem I described on both .com and .onion